# Returning react-context provider from a custom react-hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I've created a custom react hook, which manages a certain context data and returns a Component that wraps any child with that context provider as shown in the code snippet below, my only concerns are:

1- is it a good practice or at least it is OK to use this approach to keep this logic centralized

2- Does it have any impact on the app performance in general

3- Is there any other way to use the context provider while keeping the hook very abstract?

this shows the implementation of my custom hook which I'm also reusing to access the context:

```
const NotificationsProvider = props => {
  const socket = useSocket();

  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState<any>([]);
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  ....
  .... implementation
  ....

  return (
    <Provider
      value={{
        setRead,
        notifications,
        unreadCount,
        isFetching
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Provider>
  );
};

function useNotifications() {
  const { setRead, notifications, unreadCount } = useContext(
    NotificationsContext
  );
  return {
    NotificationsProvider,
    setRead,
    notifications,
    unreadCount
  };
}

export default useNotifications;
```

this code shows how i'm using it on my root component:

```
function App() {
  const { NotificationsProvider } = useNotifications();
  ....
  ....
  ....
  return (
    <NotificationsProvider>
       ....
    </NotificationsProvider>
  );
}

export default hot(App);
```

please note that I'm using the provider only once to wrap the root component (upper most container), and reusing `useNotifications` hook again in child component to access this provider, the goal is to achieve maximum abstraction so you don't need to care about where this data is stored or how it's internally implemented, also, the goal of the component is to access the notifications.

Comment: I don't understand your use case. Wrapping your App in the Provider allows every component to use it with `useContext(NotificationsContext)`. Why would you need to render the same provider again further down your app? By definition, if your `useNotifications` hook can access the context, then the component you use the hook in can also access the context as the context must be a parent of both. Your `useNotifications` hook seems to just be limiting the accessible properties in the context, which is pointless as you can just use the context instead of using the hook.

Comment: "is it a good practice or at least it is OK to use this approach to keep my this logic centralized". You're actually doing the opposite and decentalizing the logic. You now have a context and a hook that connects straight to that context, and they both do the same thing. What's your goal here? You're creating abstraction with no benefit. It will only serve to confuse other developers who read your code.

Comment: @JMadelaine in the second code snippet, I'm using the provider to wrap my `Root component` only and only once so I have one provider, then I'm using `useNotifications` hook again in any child component to access the data, adding a level of abstraction so that if the data storage has been changed (whether I have placed it in redux), or kept as is, other developers will only care about what kind of functions/data does this hook return instead of where is it stored or what functions should they use to mutate the app notifications state, does that make any sense now?

Comment: If your goal is to abstract the Context implementation, why are you talking about exposing the `Provider` in your hook? That would break the abstraction.

Comment: that's also another point I need to add to my question, do you have any other approach in mind? @JMadelaine

Comment: @JMadelaine also let me get right, why exposing the `Provider` would break the abstraction? I'm letting other developers use the `Provider` to deal with the data, but the inner implementation is still fully hidden

Comment: Oh I see, the Provider is an abstraction too. I still don't see why you need to pass a provider out with the context props. Surely the context props are enough on their own? Like I said before, anywhere that you can access the context (i.e. anywhere that you are able to render `useNotifications`, the provider will already be accessible, so there's no reason to do it.